# When I change the position of a sprite, it continues moving on its own

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a Snake-game using Phaser.js but I get stuck when it comes to moving the head around.

To make it easier on myself, I've opted to not use any velocity and handle movement by manually setting the coordinates of the sprite, my theory being that this will make it easier to handle movement once the snake grows and every segment needs to move to the same position the segment in front of it used to occupy. I basically plan to treat my game-world as a grid, and that's not going to be very easy if everything has a velocity.

I have an `update` function that should move my sprite every 50th time it's called.

```
function update() {
    snake.body.velocity.x = 0;
    snake.body.velocity.y = 0;

    if (cursors.up.isDown && direction !== 'down') {
        direction = 'up';
    } else if (cursors.down.isDown && direction !== 'up') {
        direction = 'down';
    } else if (cursors.left.isDown && direction !== 'right') {
        direction = 'left';
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown && direction !== 'left') {
        direction = 'right';
    }

    if (updateCount % 50 === 0) {
        moveSnake();
    }
    updateCount += 1;
}

function moveSnake() {
    switch(direction) {
        case 'up': snake.y -= 2; break;
        case 'down': snake.y += 2; break;
        case 'left': snake.x -= 2; break;
        case 'right': snake.x += 2; break;
    }
}
```

But this seems to trigger som kind of velocity even though I'm explicitly setting it to 0. The snake (let's pretend it looks like one) will keep moving 2 pixels at a time until the next time `moveSnake` gets called, at which point it will pick up the pace and move 4 pixels at the time untill it hits the edge of the gaming area.

I've created the sprite in the `create` function and enabled the arcade physics engine like this:

```
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);

snake = game.add.sprite(400, 300, 'snake-body');
game.physics.enable(snake, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
snake.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
```

I've verified that the throttling in `update` works and that `moveSnake` does not get called on every game-loop.

Full source at [github](https://github.com/ivarni/snake/blob/0.0.1/src/snake.js) (but there's honestly not much more there than what I've just pasted here)

*EDIT*

To clear up a bit of confusion, in my code `moveSnake` only gets invoked 3 times (try adding a breakpoint) and I expected the sprite to have moved only 6 pixels over these 3 invocations, but instead it moves 400 pixels. My question was why the x-coordinate of the sprite changes on its own and not only when I explicitly set it.

Comment: You're directly modifying the x and y positions in `moveSnake` instead of applying the velocity to them. It should be something more like `snake.x += snake.body.velocity.x`.

Comment: @MikeC I don't want it to have a velocity. I want to move the sprite a given amount of pixels and then I want it to keep still untill I tell it to move again.

Comment: The velocity can be the number of pixels to move. The problem is that you're telling it "move 2 pixels in some direction every frame". Why do you expect it to stay still when you're updating the position constantly in `moveSnake`?

Comment: @MikeC I'm not updating the position constantly, `moveSnake` only gets to be invoked 3 times in the demo before the sprite has moved off-screen. It's only invoked when the counter modulo 50 is equal to 0, which happens on every 50th execution of `update`. I expected it to stay still those other 49 times `update` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the x and y yourself, let the physics handle it, by giving body, the according velocity.

```
function moveSnake() {
    snake.body.velocity.x = 0;
    snake.body.velocity.y = 0;

    switch(direction) {
        case 'up': snake.body.velocity.y = -2; break;
        case 'down': snake.body.velocity.y = 2; break;
        case 'left': snake.body.velocity.x = -2; break;
        case 'right': snake.body.velocity.x = 2; break;
    }
}
```

Also you can ask your questions on [Phaser forums](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/14-phaser/).

Comment: So I guess there's no way around using velocity then? My issue with doing that is that when I add another segment to the snake, that segment has to "copy" the movement that every other segment did, which wasn't trivial to pull off when using velocity. I'm still curious about why my code acted the way it did.

Comment: Well, velocity is constant, It's always 2. Only depends on the direction which you know, and calculate the velocity from. Setting the position yourself is bypassing the physics. You can do it, but know you are bypassing the physics.

Comment: Fair enough. If setting the position manually is something I shouldn't be doing then the answer to my question is pretty much "Don't do it like that". I can accept that and find a different approach. Cheers.

Comment: FWIW this is what I was trying to do (obviously with less flickering): https://ivarni.github.io/snake/. I ended up using tweens rather than setting position manually.

Comment: There is a Snake example in the Phaser Examples (http://examples.phaser.io/debug.php?f=arcade%20physics/snake.js) - personally I would only use physics to move the head, then the body can just be positioned manually based on the head location. That is what the code sample I linked to does anyway.

Comment: @PhotonStorm Yeah, I had a look at that before I started and took some inspiration from it. That's actually where I got the idea to set the position manually. I guess it works in that example because they're not enabling physics for the body, but that's something I need since in the traditional snake-game you loose if you crash into your tail. I've solved it with using tweens with a very short duration. Will probably post an additional answer here once I've polished it a bit.